# How can I concatenate a big list of unique words once?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

It is hard to explain what I am trying to say so I am best off giving an example.

Lets say I had the following data -

word1, word2
word3, word4

What I would need is an output is the following -

word1 word2
word1 word3
 
word1 word4
 
word2 word1
word2 word3
word2 word4
 
word3 word1
word3 word2
word3 word4
word4 word1
word4 word2
word4 word3

So a complete mix of all the combinations of words. In total I have 300x300 rows and columns so I know it will be a big result but do not know the best way to go about this. I tried concatenating but it will take too much manual work and is not efficient at all. Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: I wrote a quick vba routine to do what I thought was needed, bu upon reading this I've deleted. Your example is a 2x2 (4 values) and produces `4!-4` results (12). So with a 300x300 grid of 90000 values in to `N!-N` results would be insanely high. You won't be holding them in excel anyway.

Comment: According to [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=how+many+unique+combinations+in+90000), the result of 90000 unique combinations 5.07x10²⁷⁰⁹² which isn't going to fit into any hard drive on the market let alone excel.

Comment: LOL and here I was about to ask if `word1 word2` was considered different or not from `word2 word1`  I had not even got around to counting possible outcomes yet.

Comment: @JNevill  Did I forget how to do a factorial?  4x3X2x1?  if that is correct isn't n!-n with n=4 actually 20?  Not poking fun, I hated my permutation and combinations course,  30 years later and its still giving me issues!

Comment: Is the number of combination n*(n-1)? so 90K * 89999 = 8 099 910 000 possibilities or lets just say a hair over 8 billion, which still does not fit in excel.  I am guessing here but another way of writing it would be n!/(n-2)!  where 2 represents the number of choices in the out come.

Comment: Do you think I could make a java application to display this? Would this be a better way, Just to put all my words in a stupidly long array and have them print all the combonations off in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate cells easily using & in your formula, try 
     =A1 & ", " & B1

Once you get it working you can simply drag it down to cover all rows